# case insensitive search for labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why this code doesn't work

```
MATCH (n) WHERE labels(n)=~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' RETURN distinct labels(n)
```

**Type mismatch: expected String but was Collection (line 1, column 17 (offset: 16))**

But this does

```
match n-[r]-() where type(r)=~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*' return distinct type(r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`labels(n)` returns a collection and not a scalar. `type(r)` always returns a scalar as it is single valued.

Try `labels(n)[0]` instead and it should work.

Doing case insensitive substring matching on labels is not recommended in a large data set.

Comment: OR `ANY(l in labels(n) WHERE l =~ '(?i).*SUBSTRING.*') ` but it will not be fast, so it should only be subsequent filtering !! Otherwise I'd use toUpper or toLower and exact search or at least suffix / post-fix search. You can also use `head(labels(n)) =~ ...`